# How to add parameters to flyway build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, groovy, flyway

I have this in my build.gradle file:

```
    flyway {
        url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DB'
        user = 'user'
        password = 'pass'
        driver = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
        placeholderReplacement = true
        schemas = ['OWNER']

    println "PRINT ARG:"
    println testArg

    locations = ["filesystem:soem-path/common"]
    placeholders = [
            'some.store.owner': flyway.schemas[0],
            'some.user'           : 'USER',
    ]
}
```

The build always fails after I added that part with the testArg. I wanted to get it in like this:

```
./gradlew flywayMigrate -PtestArg=test -Dflyway.configFiles=../flyway/flyway-dev.properties -i
```

The error message is:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'testArg' for object of type org.flywaydb.gradle.FlywayExtension.
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.getProperty(ConfigureDelegate.java:130)
```

How can I get a property in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
def devEnv = System.properties.containsKey("devEnv")


flyway {
    .....
    if (devEnv) {
        locations += "filesystem:some/path"
    }
    ....
}
```

and call flyway like this:

```
./gradlew flywayClean -DdevEnv -Dflyway.configFiles=...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the that when you are within the `flyway` configuration closure (i.e. the `flyway { ... }` section), your delegate object (i.e. when a property is not found in your local code, what class gradle will look in next) is the flyway extension. In other words, while you are in `flyway { ... }`, gradle will look for any property not found immediately in your code in the flyway plugin code.

What you are looking for is properties on the gradle `project` object. You could for example do something like this:

```
ext {
  projectProperty = { name ->
    project.hasProperty(name) ? project.properties[name] : null
  }
}

flyway { 
  def testArg = projectProperty('testArg')
  println "project property testArg: ${testArg}"
}
```

(untested, but should work in principle at least).

where the `hasProperty` call makes sure that the code doesn't break when the property is not set for the project.

For an explanation of delegation for groovy closures, the groovy language docs have [a section specifically explaining this](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegation_strategy).